# I am getting wrong value and warning when I am using recursive function warning

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I am trying to finding the smallest node data from bst using recursive function.
This is the data type that I have defined for the creation of the tree.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct treeNode{                
    struct treeNode *lc;
    int data;
    struct treeNode *rc;
};
typedef struct treeNode *BSTPTR;
```

I have written a recursive function to find the smallest node of the binary search tree.

```
BSTPTR minValue(BSTPTR bst){
    if(!bst) return nullptr;
    else {
        if(bst->lc) minValue(bst->lc);
        return bst;
    }
}
```

When I am writing an iterative function I am getting the correct output.

```
BSTPTR minValue(BSTPTR bst){
     while(bst->lc){
         bst=bst->lc;
    }
    return bst;
}
```

I am not putting the code to create bst here. I will just put the main function and input to the function.

```
int main()
{
    BSTPTR t1=0;
    createBST(t1);
    cout<<"Min Value: "<<minValue(t1)->data;   
    return 0;
}
```

Input: 9 7 3 45 36  40 22 4 8 5

I am getting this  warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

Comment: You call `minValue` recursively, but don't use the value this recursive call returns. As written, `minValue(anyPointer)` will always return `anyPointer` - it just returns its argument unchanged.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I didn't understand what you are saying. Can you please elaborate the sentence.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Can you please explain by using my function as example

Comment: `if(bst->lc) minValue(bst->lc);` is a no-op - it doesn't do anything (besides wasting CPU time). So your recursive implementation is equivalent to `if (!bst) return nullptr; else return bst;` which in turn is equivalent to simply `return bst;`

Comment: Can you please suggest the solution for this problem?@IgorTandetnik

Comment: Well, what's the purpose of the recursive `minValue` call? What is it supposed to do?

Comment: I am trying to find a node that has the smallest key in bst using recursive? @IgorTandetnik

Comment: minValue is the function that return the node which has the smallest key in the bst @IgorTandetnik

Comment: Right. So the purpose of the recursive call is to **return** the smallest node. Yet you discard its return value. Shouldn't you be using it in some way?

Comment: I got it. Thank you @IgorTandetnik